# Update multiple entities in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, multiple-tables

I am trying to update two tables `Situation` and `SituationCategory`, but it is not updating as mentioned in below code and image.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateSituation(int id, SituationsDto data)
{
    Situations result = _mapper.Map<SituationsDto, Situations>(data);
    result.Deleted = true;

    _context.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    SituationCategories situationCategory = new SituationCategories();

    if (result.SituationCategory != null)
    {
        if (situationCategory != null)
        {
            situationCategory.Description = result.SituationCategory.Description;
        }
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

In this screenshot, I have highlighted the data which should be updated:

[image]

Please answer

Answer (score 0):

An EF context knows nothing about objects unless you attach a given object to a context, or, you initially retrieved an object from a context.

Instead of just marking the entity as modified:

```
_context.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You'll need to call `Update()`, which, begins tracking the entity & marks it as modified, so, when you call `SaveChanges()`, changes will be written to DB:

```
_context.Update(result);
```

PS. I would only call `SaveChanges()` once, in this case, at the end of your method.

Comment: As per your suggestion it is updating only one entity. The related entities are not updating

Comment: What does your `Situation` entity look like? Do the related entities get set in the `_mapper.Map<SituationsDto, Situations>(data);` call?

Comment: It's just for map the incomming object to dbcontext property for updating the databases table but it updates only Situation table and i want to update Situation Categories table also

Comment: What you're doing in the code above is confusing.  If Situation Category has a relation to Situation, you should be sure to set that in your mapper from the DTO you are using in Situation. Then, calling `Update()` like mentioned in my answer, you should see changes in SituationCategory as well.

Comment: no SituationCategory table is not affecting when we are updating Situation table